# Why am I getting clipping at the inputs and outputs?

Tags: differential-amplifier, voltage-clipping

I have designed the below circuit in LTspice. This is used to measure the voltage drop across the shunt. I know people on this platform have said I should use a current transformer, but they are not that accurate.

[image]

Simulation results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain to me why I am getting the clipping? The gain for the amp is 40dB.

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Comment: It might be related to the power rails' voltage. If the output signal's peak is over the power rail's voltage, clipping may occur. Either change the power rails' voltage or the gain of your circuit.

Comment: Where is the mains voltage source's ground reference? Is it floating with respect to the circuit (as shown) or is one side supposed to be grounded?  If floating, the source can be trivially removed as the current source does not care what voltage drops across it.

Comment: Reviewing your post history, I see unaddressed comments regarding what you are doing. Do you really need the accuracy you claimed earlier? Does it really need to be mains referenced? Are you really trying to compete with expensive commercial offerings? Is this for a corporation, just an idle project, or what? Why not ask the most basic questions first: what accuracy and bandwidth is required for X purpose? You seem to be setting yourself up for inevitable failure, asking these incremental (and fundamental) questions.

Comment: @TimWilliams the main's voltage source is not referenced to the LV circuit. The op-amp is a differential, so does not it mean it doesn't necessarily need to be referenced to the LV ground? I have simulated this using a unity gain and it now works (See edit 1). I just have to build a separate amplification stage after the differential op amp output

Comment: First, I would increase V1 and V2 to 15 V to see if that affects the output wave shape.

Comment: @AnalogKid I only have 5V supply to play with. So I have rather used a unity gain differential op amp see edit 1. I will amplifier this

Comment: Do not force both a voltage and a current at the input. Use a resistor instead of the current source.

Comment: @sh- so you mean replace I1 with a 0.23ohm resistor?

Comment: @JoeyB Yes, you defined the voltage, so you can easily choose the resistor that leads to the desired current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at the plot of "V(vscream)". The OpAmp's output is quite clearly saturating at its +/-5V supply voltages, which causes the differential amplifier you built from it to malfunction.

Note that, since the shunt is floating, the inputs to the difference amplifier float up to half of its output voltage due to the voltage divider chain R6-R5-R3-R4-R7. This is why you see a 2.5Vp waveform at the inputs of the OpAmp. (It's half of the 5Vp at the output.)

To fix the clipping, just lower the gain. Try 22k for R6 and R7.

**Additionally, the circuit will explode dramatically if its ground is not floating with respect to the shunt.** Try grounding the negative end of V4 (your simulated mains) in the simulation and you'll see what I mean. It's an instant electrical fire. The differential amplifier is also totally unnecessary, you could just as well ground one side of the shunt to simplify the circuit. It won't make a difference to the circuit's operation since you have no galvanic isolation anyway.

And last but not least, **I hope you're aware that the entire circuit will be live at mains voltage.**

If you need a high accuracy isolated current measurement, a sensor like this one is probably your best bet: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/599/4640-X150_en-1516760.pdf (Accuracy better than 0.4%, linearity better than 0.1%, peak current >2000A)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am fully aware of the potential risks involved, the worse case being death. What do you mean by this "The differential amplifier is also totally unnecessary, you could just as well ground one side of the shunt to simplify the circuit." So by removing the opamp I can just connect sh2 to ground and sh1 goes to low noise amplifier to amplifier it by 40dB

Comment: Since you don't have any isolation, there's nothing to stop you from using one side of the shunt as ground in your circuit. Just build a simple non-inverting amplifier with the OpAmp.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it a bit easier in terms of reducing the number of components and fine tuning the LNA. This circuit will be made as an add-on to the shunt and mains voltage part. So I can calibrate the LV circuitry without needing to connect to the mains. This shoould be the safest way to test the LV circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

Sources V4 and I1 are completely isolated, and have absolutely no influence on the ground-referenced "absolute" potentials you measure at either end of R3, \$V_{SH1}\$ and \$V_{SH2}\$.

The voltage across R3 is \$V_{SH1}-V_{SH2} = I_1R_3\$, still nothing to do with V4!

Remember, the simulation is showing you potentials *with respect to ground*, so potentials \$V_{SH1}\$ and \$V_{SH2}\$ are being determined solely by U2's output, which ***is*** ground referenced. U2 is also clipping, and so you see corresponding flats in the plots of \$V_{SH1}\$ and \$V_{SH2}\$.

U2 is clipping because you have a gain of 100 which, when multiplied by the input amplitude of 70mV, is 7.0V, exceeding the op-amp's minimum and maximum outputs of ±5V.

Also, 1400A through 50μΩ? Seriously?